# Capturing Timestamp whenever List Item Set to Value

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm attempting to automate a field that tracks In Progress Change Request tickets, at the moment it relies on manual entry of the In-Progress start date to calculate the age of the field in days.

What I'm trying to set up is an automated workflow using SharePoint Designer that would grab the timestamp whenever a ticket is changed in status from New to In-Progress.

There is no automated action for this in SharePoint as far as I can tell, so any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

After searching around for ways to initiate a null value, you were on the right path, but the value kept getting rejected as a null. This is the method that I have tested and found to work excellently. The Progress Start date will not be set if it finds that a date already exists in that field, and will populate the current date whenever the Status of an Item is moved from NEW to In Progress.

Using SharePoint Designer 2013, 2010 Workflow

Answer (score 0):

Using a designer workflow is quite easy and hassle free. The only thing you really need to take care of is to create a "shadow" field of the old value before the user change.

Consider a list with a choice field "Status" you would need to make another field (Perfeably a single line of text) "Status_system". Now setup your workflow to run on every change.

Add an if statement like this `If Status != Status_system` inside this you add the part where you update the field to current date and time. Now also update the Status_system: `Status_system = Status`

And you're basically done. Now every time the workflow run it will check if the status has changed since last time a workflow was completed (Which in turn is last time the item was changed). If that's the case it will update the data field and set the system-field to the new value.

Comment: Okay I'm trying to understand your method but I'm afraid I don't follow your logic.

So say I have a field "Status" with as you say choice options.
What I'm confused at is how the date is grabbed at all in this method.
You say "Inside this you add the part where you update the field to the current date and time", how exactly does that work in SP-Desginer?

Comment: To add the date add the action 'Set field in current item' - choose the date field of the item and set it to the option Today :)

Comment: @MortenK to complete your answer, would you please describe the process of setting up the workflow to do this?